# LdapAuthenticationHttpModule is throwing errors

Tags: ldap, web8

I have configured LDAP authentication for the CME. It works fine, but every 10 minutes I see the following error in the Windows Event log:

```
Invalid user name or password. Please verify your user name or password. The user name was DOMAIN/user.

Component: LdapAuthenticationHttpModule
Errorcode: 6
User: RBCDEVESH152\sdlweb-ldap

StackTrace Information Details:
   at Tridion.Security.DirectoryService.AuthenticateUser(String userName, String password)
   at Tridion.Security.Web.LdapAuthenticationHttpModule.OnAuthenticateRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
```

Although it does not seem to have any negative effect, I would still like to understand and if possible solve this problem. Clues?

Comment: Looking at the error, it seems to be related to setting Active Directory and LDAP on the same CME server, in that case you can see this type of errors. Search on Web 8 documentation for "Authentication through Active Directory and LDAP"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would guess it's the SDL Monitoring Service whichs sends HTTP requests on a configurable interval to determine if your CM Website is still up-and-running.

It has probably not been configured with the right credentials, resulting in the authentication failure in the event log. If you check the status of the SDL Monitoring Service, it will probably indicate an issue with your CM Website.

Comment: Great tip! I will try it out tomorrow, when I'm back at the customer.

Comment: You were right. The problem should occur for every Web8 installation though, unless you take the trouble to configure the monitoring service. Out of the box, the following monitoring rule is active:
<WebDAVServiceHealthMonitor ServiceType="WebDAV" TimeoutInterval="30s" PollInterval="10m">

<Request URL="http://localhost/webdav/"/>

<Authentication Password="password" Username="username" Domain="domain" Scheme="NTLM" Host="host"/>

</WebDAVServiceHealthMonitor>